# Can the Planeswalker type be removed from permanents?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was in my local card store tonight and one of the people there mentioned some sort of combo to have multiple of the same planeswalker in play at once, involving some way to turn planeswalkers into non-planeswalkers to could avoid the Planeswalker Uniqueness Rule. He said he had some way to do this, but I didn't have a chance to hear what the actual combo was.

Now, I'm a bit skeptical of his claim, and can't figure out how to do this myself. I know [Song of the Dryads](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Song%20of%20the%20Dryads) can remove the type itself, but the side effects are counterproductive to the overall goal. On the other hand, I've seen ways of getting permanents both with every permanent type and no permanent type, so I can easily believe that some weird interaction could exist for this.

So in short, is there some interaction I'm missing that removes the planeswalker type from a card—or even better, all planeswalkers in play—to allow multiples in play?

Answer (score 1):

> 306.4. If a player controls two or more planeswalkers that share a planeswalker type, that player chooses one of them, and the rest are put into their owners' graveyards. This is called the "planeswalker uniqueness rule."

If you somehow remove or alter the planeswalker type of a planeswalker (Jace, Nissa etc are the types), you can play another Planeswalker with the same name yes.

In your example, the use of Song of the Dryads makes one of your Planeswalkers a Forest (it loses its types Planeswalker and [Name], and it gets the types Land and Forest). However, it also loses its abilities. I can't think of cards right know that just remove a type of a Planeswalker.

If it were to keep its loyalty abilities, it could use them just fine. The only restrictions for activating a loyalty abilities over the standard restrictions for activating abilities (costs, targets) is that only one of an object's loyalty abilities can be activated each turn.

Comment: I guess the issue is that once the type "Planeswalker" is gone, you also can't activate its abilities (similarly to how a creature that stops being a creature can't attack or block anymore).

Comment: @xLeitix That isn't true. If you give a creature the activated abilities of a Planeswalker (say Experiment Kraj + animated Gideon with a +1/+1 counter) it can activate Loyalty Abilities just fine. The only restrictions are it can still only activate one Loyalty Ability per turn, and for -X costs it needs to have that many counters to remove.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question at all. The question isn't asking if Song of the Dryads would allow you to have duplicate planeswalkers. It's asking if there's a way to get duplicate planeswalkers other than Song of the Dryads.

Comment: Why would it lose its abilities? I see in the rulings that it does, but I don't understand why? Other cards that change a creature often say "with no abilities"... this doesn't say that, so why won't it keep its abilities?

Comment: **305.7.** If an effect sets a land's subtype to one or more of the basic land types, the land no longer has its old land type. It loses all abilities generated from its rules text, its old land types, and any copy effects affecting that land, and it gains the appropriate mana ability for each new basic land type.

Comment: @diego Thanks. I never would have guessed that! I knew that a mountain that's become a forest would lose it's default red mana ability, but I figured it was due to no longer being a mountain. I wouldn't have thought that it applies to abilities on other permanents as well. Very interesting.

Comment: It also isn't completely clear to me that Song of the Dryads is an instance of an effect setting "a land's subtype" to one or more of the basic land subtypes. Wouldn't that only be true if it first made the permanent a land, and then gave it the subtype forest? Here it is giving the non-land permanent the land type and the forest subtype at the same time, so is it really a "land" that it's giving a subtype to?

Comment: @GendoIkari It looks like Song of the Dryads is the only card with this template (possibly the only one with this kind of effect, I can't think of anything else off the top of my head that turns any permanent into a Land and overwrites subtypes). So they are probably using the template as shorthand for "becomes a Land and gains the Forest subtype"

Comment: @Gendolkari, Forest is only a land subtype, so it must be setting a land's subtype. You're reading too much into it